# Calculate the flow (divergence) through a hemisphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, partial-derivative, divergence-theorem

Calculate the flow of $\mathbf{F} = (0, 0, y^2 + xz)$ through the hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$, $z \geq 0$, in the direction with a positive $z$-component.

I already calculated the divergence on the hemisphere and got zero. I now need to take away (subtract) the flux thru the disc that closes the hemisphere and as you can see in the question it says "in the direction with a positive z-component." Since it says that I used (0,0,1) as my normal but in the answers they used (0,0,-1). Can someone please explain why they did that?

Comment: In order to apply the divergence theorem, the orientation of the surface of solid hemisphere should be **outward**, that is in the direction with a positive $z$-component along the hemisphere and in the direction with a negative $z$-component along the disc.

Comment: @RobertZ Do you mean that when I calculated the divergence on the entire hemisphere I was integrating the outward flux (positive divergence) and thus I need to take away the outward flux using the normal that points in the negative z direction?Is that what you mean? But what if it was a negative divergence? Do I then take inward? Last but not least what does "in the direction with a positive z-component" mean in the question, what are they trying to tell me?

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) the sign of the divergence does not matter, 3) "in the direction with a positive z-component" means that the orientation is upward

Comment: But in that case how could say yes to 1)? What I meant to say is if the divergence ended up being negative, it then means that the flux is inwards which means I need to subtract an inward flux through the disc and thus I need to use a normal that point upwards?

Comment: In 1) we are talking about the orientation of the closed surface. In the statement of the divergence theorem such orientation is always outward. It is not related with the field or the sign of its divergence. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement
BTW what is your text book?

Comment: My text book is called "Calculus: A complete course". So there is no place for inwards orientation in divergence theorem, in order to calculate inwards orientation we just need to multiply it by negative one right? But I could still get a negative value for a outward orientation since there is negative divergence. All in all orientation and the sign of the divergence have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Yes to all statements